# One way replication between 2 sql servers on different networks

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016

I would like to replicate between 2 sql servers that exist in different networks. This link is not relevant to my case as the servers are not connected: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-2017

If we assume that I can get the first copy of the database and then move it to the new server, in order to set up transactional replication, is it necessary that I use a vpn?

I have checked these links but were of no help:

[SQL Server Transactional Replication over Internet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52019/sql-server-transactional-replication-over-internet)

[SQL Server replication over internet error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117647/sql-server-replication-over-internet-error)

Is there a tutorial somewhere on 1) How to do replication over the internet
2) How to do replication if a vpn is required?

More info: The source would be a sql server 2014 and the destination a sql server 2016.

Comment: Connecting the two servers over the Internet--there's no way any of us can tell you what will be required.  This may require multiple firewalls to be configured, etc.  As for a VPN, it's not required, but if you don't use a VPN then you are exposing the data to anyone that has access to the networks that have to be traversed to get from point A to point B.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Thank you. In my case, there is 1 firewall protecting the one sql server, and one firewall protecting the other one. I should allow port 1433 for these 2?

Comment: Yes, but I would highly recommend only allowing 1433 for the one IP address the traffic will be coming from on the other end.  If you allow any IP address through on port 1433, you're opening SQL Server up to hacking attempts.  You need serious security hardening here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @TonyHinkle Is there a tutorial for setting the connection up through SSMS?